# How does mypy detect pyi files?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to set up type checking for a module, but the pyi file isn't being applied. I sense that I'm making some stupid mistake somewhere, but I can't work out what it is.

Here's what I tried:

blah.pyi file:

```
def func(x : int) -> int : ...
```

blah.py file:

```
def func(x):
    return x

reveal_type(func)
print(func(''))
```

Directory structure:

```
root
|- blah.pyi
|- blah.py
```

Mypy command:

```
...\root> python -m mypy blah.py
blah.py:4: note: Revealed type is "def (x: Any) -> Any"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
...\root> python -m mypy.stubtest blah.py
error: blah.py failed to find stubs
Stub:
MISSING
Runtime:
N/A
```

Comment: Stubs apply to modules, not to scripts/files. `python -m mypy.stubtest blah` picks up on `blah.pyi`